# Component is not rendering with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I made a few routes, but my components don't render when I click on the links. I don't get any errors, the components, except for Navbar, simply don't render. BrowswerHistory yields the same result. I'm using react-router 3.0.0 version. What is wrong with my router structure?

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute,  hashHistory} from 'react-router';

const router = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Navbar}>
            <IndexRoute  component={Main}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path="other" component={Other}></Route>
            <Route path="aboutus" component={AboutUs}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
    );


   ReactDOM.render(
    router,
     document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

Navbar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
class Navbar extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
 <nav>
  <ul className="menu-list">
    <li className="menu-item">
      <Link to="/" className="menu-link">Main</Link>
    </li>
    <li className="menu-item">
      <Link to="aboutus" href="" className="menu-link">About Us</Link>
    </li>
    <li className="menu-item">
      <Link to="other" className="menu-link">Some other item</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
  );
 }
}

 export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you forgot this part: `{this.props.children}`. You need to specify the place where you want to `render` your child component.

**Reason why this is required**: `NavBar` is main component, all other component will `render` inside this, so you need to use `{this.props.children}`, at this place child component will `render`.

Use this:

```
return (
  <nav>
    <ul className="menu-list">

      <li className="menu-item">
        <Link to="/" className="menu-link">Main</Link>
      </li>

      <li className="menu-item">
        <Link to="aboutus" href="" className="menu-link">About Us</Link>
      </li>

      <li className="menu-item">
        <Link to="other" className="menu-link">Some other item</Link>
      </li>

    </ul>
    {this.props.children} //added this line
  </nav>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out yet another time!